# What is the button beside the VDC control on a 2001 Subaru Legacy VDC model

Tags: subaru, windshield

There is a button that looks like a demister on the dash beside the VDC button that I have no idea what it does. There is already demister buttons else ware in the car so it must be something different.[image: Random Demister]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The Subaru Legacy owner's manual indicates that button is your windshield wiper deicer.  Pictured below is part of page 3-38 of the manual.  The manual explains how to use the deicer in this picture.

[image: Subaru Legacy Owner's Manual]

Comment: Mate you are full of cutouts from manuals. You have answered two of my questions in less than 1 day. Well done. Does this mean that it only deices the wipers so they can move freely or will it also deice the windscreen? I am taking it as it only does the wipers.

Comment: Can I also ask where you get all your owners manuals from?

Comment: @WillNZ This particular manual I found on [subaru.com](http://www.subaru.com/owners/resource-center/owners-manuals/search.html) but, it varies.  Sometimes I have a knack for research.  I assume the deicer would only be for the wipers and that you would still need to use your defog setting on the heater to deice the whole windshield.  I love answering questions that include photos, thanks for that.